# Drop down menu won't allow me to click the login button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use the z-index so that both my login button can be clickable and also my drop down menus can be shown in front of a table but from my understanding, must I assign a number from the most importance to the least? If I do that, then I can't get my login button to work because it is less important than making my drop down menus to be infront...

```
div.nav ul, div.nav li, label{
  line-height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 2em;
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  font-weight: 100;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 6;
}
```

Comment: your dropdown needs the z-index. also without code we cannot help you at all.

Comment: I do have a z-index of 0 in my drop down menu

Comment: Sorry, I gave it a z-index of 6

Comment: but for my logout button, I gave it lower z-index and hence I can't logout when the drop down menu is activated

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mcve], and edit your question accordingly.